# How to parse LinkedIn timestamp to human readable

Tags: javascript, unix, timestamp, epoch

I looked at various examples on the net; however, i cannot seem to the get the LinkedIn timestamp to parse correctly.

Inpeticualy the year.

What am i missing here?

1352236307000

```
      function parseTwitterDate(epoch) {
                    var newDate = new Date();
                    newDate.setTime(epoch * 1000);
                    dateString = newDate.toUTCString();
                    return dateString;
                };
```

Posted Sun, 30 Aug 44820 04:23:20 GMT

Comment: People landing on this question might also be interested in converting a LinkedIn post URL to a human-readable timestamp https://stackoverflow.com/a/72415986/470749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple pass this in as a param to the date constructor:

```
new Date(1352236307000).toLocaleString()
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to return with-out the [GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] portion of Tue Nov 06 2012 15:11:47 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

Comment: Here is the full Javascrtip API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date , you can pretty much do anything.

Comment: it says integer number is to long

Comment: If you get an error with the length of the integer, try dividing the timestamp by 1000, it's in milliseconds so will not produce a valid result otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's in milliseconds. Just divide with 1000.

Comment: No. It's the total milliseconds since 1/1/1970, division by 1000, would give seconds since 1/1/1970.